# ASP .NET Validators broken in FireFox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I'm struggling with ASP .NET Validators JavaScript issue. Following function (part of framework generated code) tries to access **validatioGroup** attribute value using **control.Field** syntax. It works fine in IE, however in FF that value is always **undefined**. Consequently, validation always passes and my validation scenario is broken... Is there a way to get round it?

```
function IsValidationGroupMatch(control, validationGroup) {
 if ((typeof(validationGroup) == "undefined") || (validationGroup == null)) {
 return true;
 }
 var controlGroup = "";
 if (typeof(control.validationGroup) == "string") {
 controlGroup = control.validationGroup;
 }
 return (controlGroup == validationGroup);
}
```

Thanks, Pawel

Comment: what version of .net? are you using ajax extensions?

Comment: Framework version in IIS is set to 2. Do I use ajax extension? Hm, how to check it?

Comment: IIS will show framework 2.0 for 2.0 and 3.5 (two different version numbers, though) - you should look at your project and see what version of the framework you're using.

Comment: It's 3.5 in project properties.

Comment: @dragonfly are you using the `ScriptManager` or `UpdatePanel` controls?

Comment: Nope. Only plain ASP .NET controls + validators.

Comment: Ups , sorry . There is a ScriptManager control used on that page, it's added magically in page base class - I haven't spotted it before.

Comment: OK. To sum up: references to System.Web.Extension etc. in my Web Application Project point to 3.5 version. Page with above issue uses ScriptManager (I perform some asmx calls). Yet still, I can't get my ASP .NET validators to work - seems like they are not cross-browser, is it true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
<xhtmlConformance mode="Strict"/>
```

I had that line in web.config . Setting to default value, which is **Transitional** fixed the issue. Here is a background of the topic: [Client side validation in FF](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/rbirkby/archive/2006/11/01/Client_2D00_side-validation-in-Firefox.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If ASP.NET (incorrectly) [determines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx) the browser doesn't support validation via client side scripting then the validation will only be performed on the server side.

**But** server side validation only seems to happen if your event handler includes the `Page.IsValid` check at the start of the event handler method.

It's good practice to include this check anyway in case the browser has javascript disabled.

```
public void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsValid) return;

    ... the rest of your event handler ....

}
```